# Typescript variable initialization and type assignment

Tags: typescript

```
var confirm_origin_button = state.mapProps.origin_marker
      ? {
          first_text: "Confirm your starting point",
          // second_text: "Confirm Origin Stop",
          first_button_text: "Confirm",
          first_button_func: confirm_origin,
        }
      : {
          first_text:
            "Zoom into one of the shaded areas and tap on a marker to select a starting point.",
        };
```

I don't quite understand what this line is doing. I know that whatever after colon indicates the type of the variable `confirm_origin_button`, but why is there a question mark (which i think means optional) and a curly bracket after `state.mapProps.origin_marker`?

Comment: `?` `:` is the conditional operator. Here, `{ ... }` denotes an object literal

Comment: Oh. You are saying that ? xxx : yyy is a ternary conditional statement. Right? Thanks so much!